# How to solve this Problem Could not serialize the XCom value into JSON

Tags: python, airflow

How to solve this problem??
I don't know what to do....

My Dags

```
def _game():
    game_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['match', 'puuid']
    input_data = {'match':match100,'puuid':game_content['puuid']}
    game_df = game_df.append(input_data, ignore_index=True)
    return game_df

def _game_score():
    game_df = _game()
    
create_data_df = PythonOperator(
    task_id = 'create_data_df',
    python_callable=_game,
    dag=dag
)
data_processing = PythonOperator(
    task_id = 'data_processing',
    python_callable=_game_score,
    dag=dag
)
```

My Airflow logs

```
[2022-09-19, 12:58:11 UTC] {python.py:173} INFO - Done. Returned value was:              match, puuid
KR_6078406478, CLsxdELas_df67weR
[2022-09-19, 12:58:11 UTC] {xcom.py:586} ERROR - Could not serialize the XCom value into JSON. If you are using pickle instead of JSON for XCom, then you need to enable pickle support for XCom in your *** config.
[2022-09-19, 12:58:11 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1909} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 68, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 2412, in xcom_push
    session=session,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 68, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/xcom.py", line 198, in set
    map_index=map_index,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/xcom.py", line 583, in serialize_value
    return json.dumps(value).encode('UTF-8')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type DataFrame is not JSON serializable
```

Then error occur _game(): return game_df
What Mean json serializable?
My DataFrame is connected Json?
And how to solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, airflow is a workflow manager, so it has limited capabilities to transfer data between tasks and you should not passing data between tasks.

so xcom doesn't support exchanging non serialized data type like dataframes (read more about Python pickle [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)),
but if you must , you need to make `custom xcom backend`.

for more information , see [here](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/custom-xcom-backends/)

Comment: Thank you for help and comment
Then i should reduce my dataframe or custom xcom backend??

Comment: @lima you can convert your dataframe to dictionary and pass it or use custom xcom , but again the best approach would be not to pass any data between tasks

Answer (score 0):

In your airflow.cfg file set, enable_xcom_pickling to True which serialises xcom to JSON.